# Find $P(X=Y=1)$ and $P(Y\le X,X\le 1)$, given two unique distributions for $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim\text{DUnif}(\{1,...,17\})$ and $Y\sim\text{Bin}(17,0.1)$, and assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

$\;\;\;$a)$\;$Find $P(X=Y=1)$.

$\;\;\;$b)$\;$Find $P(Y\le X,X\le 1)$.

I'm not exactly sure where to start with either of these.

The first one I tried binomial distribution:$\;\binom{17}{1}(0.1)(0.9)^{16}$, but that's incorrect.

Comment: For the first one, you only computed $P(Y=1)$. The question asks for $P(X=Y=1)$. Since $X,Y$ are independent, $P(X=Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)$. Thus, you need to multiply by $P(X=1)$, which is $\frac{1}{17}$.

Comment: For (b) the method is similar, as $X \le 1$ does not leave many possibilities and given that then $Y \le X$ is rather restrictive too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a), you only computed $P(Y=1)$.

The question asks for $P(X=Y=1)$.

Since $X,Y$ are independent, $P(X=Y=1)=P(X=1)P(Y=1)$.

Thus, you need to multiply by $P(X=1)$, which is $\frac{1}{17}$.

For part (b), note that the event $X\le 1$ is the same as the event $X=1$, hence
\begin{align*}
P(Y\le X,X\le 1)
&=P(Y\le X,X=1)\\[4pt]
&=P(Y\le 1,X=1)\\[4pt]
&=P(Y\le 1)P(X=1)\qquad\text{[since $X,Y$ are independent]}\\[4pt]
&=\bigl(P(Y=0)+P(Y=1)\bigr)P(X=1)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so to finish it, just use the binomial probability formula to get $P(Y=0)$ and $P(Y=1)$, and use $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{17}$.